# Regular Expression: split string on line break, tab and combinations of both

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to split a string using tabs, line breaks or any combination or repetition of both.
As an example, a string such as "A\tB\nC\t\tD\n\nE\t\nF\n\tG" should return
an array of "A", "B", etc. So far I've been able to get some results with this but it's not optimal:

```
a=a.replace(/\t\n/,"\t").replace(/\n\t/,"\t").split(/\t+|\n+/);
```

I'm open to any suggestions on how to improve it.

Comment: Try `.split(/[\t\n]+/)`

Comment: using `\R` instead of `\n` allows for you to catch all unicode forms of line breaks (like the carriage return line break `\r\n`). Edit: this is off topic I'm sorry

Comment: So, what is the problem here exactly?

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, your answer was exactly what I needed.
Thank you for the suggestion about \R Patrick, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex  `/[\r\n\t]+/g`.

```
"A\tB\nC\t\tD\n\nE\t\nF\n\tG".split(/[\r\n\t]+/g)

    //print ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this `"A\tB\nC\t\tD\n\nE\t\nF\n\tG".split(/\s+/)`

Comment: Thanks but in this case I need to keep the spaces. Great suggestion, though, I'll keep it in mind.